# How do I create a function that deletes an item in JavaScript for my webpage?

Tags: javascript, dom

I have an HTML page as follows:

```
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <title>Add/Delete</title>
  </head>

  <body>
    <h1>List of Items</h1>
    <main>
      <ul id="items"></ul>
      <input type="text" id="newText" />
      <input type="button" value="Add" onclick="addItem()" />
    </main>
    <script src="./app3.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

and javascript as follows:

```
    let list = document.querySelector('#items');
    let input = document.getElementById('newText');
    // create Li element 
    let li = document.createElement('li');

    // set the li element text to be the input element value plus a space
    // let text = list.value + ' ';
    // li.innerText = list.value 
    // li.innerText = list.value 

    li.innerText = input.value + ' ';


    // create a tag 

    let a = document.createElement('a');
    console.log(a.nodeName); // ohh ok
    // set the a element text to be '[Delete]'

    a.innerText = '[Delete]';
    // console.log(a);
    // set the a element href attribute to #

    a.setAttribute('href', '#');
    // append the a element to the li element 

    li.appendChild(a);

    // console.log(li);
    // appent the li element to the list element

    list.appendChild(li)
    // clear the input field 

    input.value = '';

    // let x = document.getElementById('a');

    // console.log(x.nodeName);
    
}
function deleteItem(e) {
// check if the nodeName is 'A' 


// let a = doument.getElementById('a')


// if it is true remove the parent Element

}
```

What my problem is is that yes my addItem function works, but not my delete item function. How can I make it work? I'm confused about my understanding of removing and "checking if nodename is A". I understand that the parent element could be UL since the child elements will be list items. But if I'm checking if the nodeName is A then what does that mean? Please help.

Comment: Hi! Why are you using `<a>` tag for a delete button?

Answer (score 2):

You need to add a click event listener to your `<a>` element.

Under `a.setAttribute('href', '#');` add the line `a.addEventListener('click', deleteItem, {passive: true, once: true});`.

the `passive` option makes this listener non-scroll-blocking(can't remeber the correct term for this), while `once: true` removes the listener after first trigger.
It's best practice to remove unneeded event listeners.

Then do this in your delete function

```
function deleteItem(e) {
  e.preventDefault(); /// stops default anchor behaviour('href');
  let listItem = e.currentTarget.parentElement; /// selects the parent of your delete anchor
  listItem.remove(); /// removes the parent from DOM
}
```

That's it =)